# MVC Facebook apps getting login fail error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-apps

I'm new to the MVC facebook app development. I've developed a small Facebook app. I can't login. My facebook app always fails displaying this error:

```
Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

Comment: Please add relevant code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could elaborate on your issue, that'd be great. Meanwhile, you could follow a tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on). I think it's very easy to follow so I suggest you check if have followed all necessary steps.